# Can't get Pyramid to recognize Mongo

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pyramid

I am trying to get the Pyramid Web framework to handle a request using Mongo but I am a relative newbie to both. I cannot get my view to recognize a database attached to a request.

In `development.ini`:

```
###
# configure mongodb
###
mongo_uri = mongodb://localhost:27017/nomad
```

The `__init__.py` imports and `main` function:

```
# imports for Mongodb
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from gridfs import GridFS
from pymongo import MongoClient


def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
    """
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    init_includes(config)
    init_routing(config)

    db_url = urlparse(settings['mongo_uri'])
    config.registry.db = MongoClient(
        host=db_url.hostname,
        port=db_url.port,
    )

    def add_db(request):
        db = config.registry.db[db_url.path[1:]]
        if db_url.username and db_url.password:
            db.authenticate(db_url.username, db_url.password)
        return db

    def add_fs(request):
        return GridFS(request.db)

    config.add_request_method(add_db, 'db', reify=True)
    config.add_request_method(add_fs, 'fs', reify=True)
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

In `jobscontroller.py`, which is the handler view making the request:

```
import pyramid_handlers

from nomad.controllers.base_controller import BaseController

class JobsController(BaseController):

    @pyramid_handlers.action(renderer='templates/jobs/index.pt')
    def index(request):
        all_jobs = request.db['jobs'].find()
        return {'all_jobs': all_jobs}
```

I get an error:

```
all_jobs = request.db['jobs'].find()
AttributeError: 'JobsController' object has no attribute 'db'
```

I am using Pyramid handlers to manage routing and views, and I know that all of this works because all my routes resolve and deliver web pages. It's only the jobs controller that's funky, and only after I tried adding that request.db call.

Can someone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: Just curios, but which `pymongo` is installed. `pip freeze | grep pymogo` if you can run that. Notably here the documentation could do with some updating and the [`authenticate()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.authenticate) method notably is deprecated, and calling it this way when connected to MongoDB 3.6 or greater **will** have consequences. I would start by checking through stages here. See that `settings` contains what you think it does, and then that each stage of connection is doing what is expected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Neil. I am on pymongo 3.6.1 and MongoDB 3.4.7. I tried removing the authentication lines but I get the same error.

Comment: It's not simply the authentication lines ( right now ) since the code won't presently get there if at least the `urlparse` is working correctly. Do yourself a favor and start python as interactive and try at least connecting with the `pymongo` driver first. That will rule out any general connectivity issues. The very next thing you "should" do is try the same "standalone" instructions attempting to get an instance of `Confgurator` and see that it actually is reading your supplied config correctly. Those are steps you can do yourself without waiting on someone else to debug from scratch

Comment: Do you mean that the code may not be getting to the view? It definitely is - if I take the Mongo code out of the view entirely and have it return a dict then I can parse that in my template. As for checking to see if Python connects to Mongo via PyMongo, I did that before trying to integrate with Pyramid. I can get it to connect and write to the db using a basic:

c = MongoClient(host="localhost", port=27017). 

So I am still stumped. I am considering trying to find a scaffold and recreating my project, but would rather try and fix this so I can understand what's missing/incorrect.

Comment: No I just mean the authenticate line because there is no user in the url. Your problem is that `db` is not defined, so something in the connection process is failing. Either that's the connection ( and you've confirmed you've debugged that ) or the config simply is not being correctly read. Those are the two points of failure here. So make sure the config is being read correctly.

Comment: Thanks - good thing to check. However: 
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> config.read('development.ini')
['development.ini']
>>> print(config.get('app:main','mongo_uri'))
mongodb://localhost:27017/nomad

Comment: I've confirmed that the db object is being returned by the add_db function in the __init__.py file. Also changed the /nomad database name to database name /jobs. Analyzing the request object while debugging the jobs_controller file reveals this error message: "'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'jobs' method on a 'MongoClient' object it is failing because no such method exists." Why would the database object not be callable, and why does it think that I am calling a jobs method rather than accessing a jobs database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not referring to the request - you're referring to the object itself (usually named `self`, but you have named it `request` - which would work if it was just a function and not a method on an object). Since you're inside an object of a class, the first parameter is always the object itself:

```
class JobsController(BaseController):
    @pyramid_handlers.action(renderer='templates/jobs/index.pt')
    def index(self, request):
        all_jobs = request.db['jobs'].find()
        return {'all_jobs': all_jobs}
```

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh.